# Opensuse Leap script to unmount NFS mount before shutdown or reboot

Tags: linux, script, mount, shutdown, nfs

I have a problem to shutdown/reboot my Laptop when I have my NFS mounted.
It takes a very long time to shutdown/reboot.
In my fstab is:

> 192.168.x.x:/RAID5    /NAS    nfs4    defaults,_netdev,noauto,users,minorversion=1 0 0

The user can mount and unmount the NFS in Dolphin file manager.
When I umount the NFS before shutting down the system it almost instantly shuts down.
I linked also the **halt** script to **init.0/6** with **umount /NAS** but didn't help.
Does anybody has a solution for my problem?